# Difference between 助ける【たすける】 and 救う【すくう】

Tags: word-choice, meaning, nuances, verbs

What is the difference between the verbs 助ける【たすける】 and 救う【すくう】?

Apparently, both mean *to save*.

---

When searching on Google, I found the same question asked on Yahoo! 知恵袋:

> [『助ける』と『救う』の意味の違いを教えてください。](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1066562850)

I was able to understand the question, but my Japanese knowledge is far from enough to understand the answer. Anyway, it would be helpful to have this question asked in English so other beginners could have a chance.

Comment: I know that you use 救う, never 助ける, talking about salvation in a theological sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

助ける means to help. Not to save. About the same as extend a helping hand.

救う means to save. When helping suffering people and talking about religions, you can use this.

In everyday life, you should *not* use 救う. It sounds odd.

Comment: "regions"っていうのは"religions"のことですか？

Comment: @broccoliforest はい、変換ミスです。。。 直しました